# Node application with Forever in background, how to bring it to foreground

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

Running a node application in the background using Forever in Ubuntu 16.04, any command line to bring the process to foreground to monitor it?

to start an application in the background

```
forever -w application.js
```

to check list of processes

```
forever list
```

What command line can be used to bring particular process to foreground?

PS. I know of logs but I'm looking for a way to bring the process to foreground.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forever logs` to see the logs of your application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: I know about logs but any other command line to bring the process to foreground?

Comment: What do you mean by bringing the process to foreground?